# ultrasound Image processing using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new to image processing have few questions. I need to create images from some raw data from an ultrasound. 2d array . I need to form an image from the top of the data propogate the signal of original strennght of one million downward, then attenuate the signal by the value in the attenuating image file and if the succeeding impedance value in the acoustic impedance map has a different impedance, propagate the echo upward. I need a bit of guidance on how to approach this. Any suggestions are much appreciated . thanks

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear. Please provide example data, images and some literature where you get your todos from.

Comment: yep we are programmers not oracles we do not know what are you writing about ... add some images (even sketch would do) of your setup and exactly what you need help with. add sample data of input and expected output etc... what you mean by array (Phase array perhaps? is it really 2D or just linear and you should create 2D image?) from the vagueness of your text I got the feeling you want to drive the array instead of reconstruct data into image ... so which is it?